# Google Chrome extension to save an image to Dropbox

Tags: chrome, images, dropbox

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can save an image located on a webpage to my Dropbox account (e.g. right clicking on the image > save to Dropbox). I don't want to manually have to save the image, go to my Dropbox account, upload it there.

I use Google Chrome with Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension is called [Download to Dropbox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-to-dropbox/mklccdhnpppcmbpbkaanmamjfmmefbnp), but sometimes you have to open the image in new tab before you right click -> Upload to Dropbox, or it will save what looks like the page source.

It seems to also work with other types of files, including PDF.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works great! Indeed sometime need to open in a separate tab.